# How to change the icon color of PopupMenu (Material Design 3 )in Android?

Tags: android, popupmenu, material-design-3

I am trying to implement a `PopupMenu` in my app following this [example](https://m3.material.io/components/menus/implementation).
It works, but I can't change the icon color. How would I achieve that?

Meanwhile I could change the background color:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.App.PopupMenu</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorSecondary</item> // <--- This one has no effect
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.Material3.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_back</item> // <-- This changes background and it works good.
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorSecondary</item> // <--- Even placed here still doesn't work
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorSecondary</item> // <-- even with android:
</style>
```

I am using the new `Material Design 3` library from Google.

Also, I tried to find something on Internet and I could only find solutions for my issue regarding `PopupMenu` on `Toolbar`, which is not my case. I need a `PopupMenu` when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I previously searched for a solution to this problem and found this solution the best (even night mode can be supported)

in your menu.xml file
In the following example it menu_items_options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:title="share"
        android:icon="@drawable/round_ios_share_24"
        app:iconTint="?attr/colorOnSurface"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_select"
        android:title="select"
        android:icon="@drawable/round_select_all_24"
        app:iconTint="?attr/colorOnSurface"
        />

</menu>
```

add

```
app:iconTint="?attr/colorOnSurface"
```

You can change to the "?attr/colorOnSurface" color you want (and it is better to use what I mentioned) for a better experience with day and night mode

Note: "app:iconTint" Not "android:iconTint"